# How to resize text dynamically along with window resizing in wxWidgets?

Tags: user-interface, text, resize, wxwidgets

I want to make something simple, inside a panel, have a text that **resizes** when you **resize the window**. I tried with a wxBoxSizer, doesn't work the way I naively hoped.

```
    wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    wxStaticText* scalable_text = new wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, "This text resizes nicely");
    sizer->Add(scalable_text);

    this->SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
```

Do I have to make a *custom text class* and catch a "resize" event?
If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: what doesn't work? How do you test it, what do you expect and what actually happened?

Comment: What do you mean how do I test it? As in what I expected, I expected it to resize the actual text, whereas nothing happened

Comment: what I mean is whether you want the extra to resize when you resize the container (panel/window), when you change some parameter of the font, as Vadim  guessed or you move the container between monitors with different DPI? Or maybe you do smth completely different? Please explain exactly how do you test it.

Comment: @Igor, yes I do want it to resize when I resize the container (panel/sizer), NOT when I move between monitors with diff DPI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wxStaticText` doesn't get resized because you didn't specify neither a non-zero proportion to resize it in the sizer direction (vertically here) nor `wxEXPAND` flag to resize it in the other direction (horizontally), but even if it were resized, the problem is that resizing it doesn't change its font size and I think it would be very weird if it did this by default.

So if you want to change the font size, you do need to do it yourself. Of course, you don't need to define a custom class to do it, you can just do something like

```cpp
scalable_text->Bind(wxEVT_SIZE, [=](wxSizeEvent& e) {
  auto f = scalable_text->GetFont();
  f.SetPixelSize(wxSize(0, e.GetSize().y / 2)); // or whatever...
  scalable_text->SetFont(f));
  scalable_text->Refresh();
});
```

And you should also tell the sizer to resize this element

```cpp
   sizer->Add(scalable_text, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I needed! Except, wxSizeEvent is called only when the window (my whole app) is resized, If I were to put my text inside an actual Sizer, what event should I catch? wxSizerSizeEvent or something like that?

Comment: @BigVotka2in1, did you try it? The event is bound to the control, so it will execute when the control changes the size.

Comment: @BigVotka2in1 Sorry, I overlooked that your original code didn't actually resize the element neither. I've updated the answer now.